# Cannot set properties of null (setting 'image')

Tags: javascript, html

someone help please my image won’t load and I get a error

document.getElementById("task").image = "url"

I made sure the Id matches the id in html I don’t know what’s wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `image` to change the image of an `<img>`. To do it you will need to use `src`.
Here is what you need below.

```
document.getElementById("task").src = "yoururl"
```

Comment: still wont work :/

Comment: Do you mind showing me your console? And are you changing the "yoururl" to the path of which the image is?

Comment: ohhhh wow ok I am stupid I am sorry it works now thank u

Comment: Glad I could help! Have a nice day and welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

To change the image source, you can try the code below.

```js
const img = document.querySelector("task");
img.setAttribute("src", "<url>");
```

`setAttribute()` will set the `src` attribute to your URL of your image.

Make sure to change *<url>* with your image URL!

---

You can also use the code below.

```js
const img = document.querySelector("task");
img.src = "<url>";
```

Setting the source to your URL will correctly render the image.

Make sure to change *<url>* with your image URL!

Comment: I got it to work already thank u